# How to Bind Embedded Image with variable ImageSource that is specified by a string in C# code behind?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding

I want to display variable Image in Xamarin Forms. I want to bind `ImageSource` in XAML. I have tried using `IMarkupExtension` as mentioned in the docs, but the limitation is I need to specify whole path in the XAML itself. I want to bind `ImageSource` that can be varied whenever required. I don't want to specify whole path in XAML.

**Here is my working XAML code:**

```xml
<Image Source="{local:ImageResource MyProject.Images.photo.jpg}" />
```

**Here is XAML the code that is not working:**

```xml
<Image Source="{Binding imgSource StringFormat=local:ImageResource `MyProject.Images.{0}`" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft doesn't provide information about Binding variable ImageSource in XAML in the official documentation. You need `IValueConverter` and `ImageSource.FromResource()` to convert `string` to `ImageSource` in order to bind variable Image.

Set your Image as **Build: EmbeddedResource** in Image Properties.

**Here is the Extension for Converting**

```cs
public class EmbeddedToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string fileName && parameter is string assemblyName)
        {
            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Assembly Name: " + assemblyName);  // Just for reference, remove in Release mode
                var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(assemblyName + "." + fileName, typeof(EmbeddedToImageSourceConverter).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
                return imageSource;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return value;
            }
        }
        else
            return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

**In your XAML**

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             ...
             xmlns:extensions="clr-namespace:MyProject.Extensions">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <extensions:EmbeddedToImageSourceConverter x:Key="imageConverter" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="{Binding IconSource, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}, ConverterParameter='MyProject.Resources.Images'}"
                           HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="40" Aspect="AspectFit" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**In C# Code Behind (xaml.cs)**

```cs
public string IconSource { get { return "photo.png"; } set { } }

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = this;
}
```

You can set BindingContext to your ViewModel and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` which will sync IconSource image in your XAML with C# code.

**Note** that I am getting Intellisense error/warning at line `<Image Source="{Binding IconSource, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}, ...` near starting curly brace of StaticResource imageConverter. The error says **No DataContext found for Binding "**. But the code is **working** fine. Anyone who would explain the reason for the error or would improve the sample code to remove the error are most welcome. Edit the answer if you find the cause.